# Creating an Ember.js component for each table row causes the width to change?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-components

In my Ember.js application, I have a standard HTML table inside a Hanldebars template like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John Doe</td>
            <td>john.d@gmail.com</td>
            <td>111-111-1111</td>
        </tr>
        <tr colspan="3">
            <td><!-- Loads of other markup  --></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This works fine but, I have to turn each table row into a component in order to add some logic etc. Instead of directly adding the rows, I now have:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each people as |person|}}
            {{table-row person=person}}
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, I now have a component called table-row which has the entire first and second (with colspan="3") `<tr>` elements from the above HTML. The problem is, when I insert it as a component, Ember wraps the two rows in a `<div>` and this causes the rows to show up awkwardly. It doesn't take the width of the table and the table head. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

In your component definition, override `tagName` property.

The following sample code is from my *data-grid-row* component:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName:'',

  ...
});
```

If you don't override this `tagName`, a *div* will be created for you.

Have a look at [the resource from Ember Guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/components/customizing-a-components-element/#toc_customizing-the-element)